# How to write conditional select query in mysql

Tags: php, mysql

I want to write a Login authentication query,

I want to check user Login and password if that is found in my database i fetch his details  however if i cant find exact details i want to check if only the provided username exist in the table and get his name and profile pic.

i can do some thing like ..

```
SELCT * FROM `use_table` WHERE `username` = 'something' AND `password` = 'something'
```

if the above query returns empty rows then i fire another query

```
SELCT `name`, `profile_pic` FROM `use_table` WHERE `username` = 'something'
```

**I can do this using multiple queries but the tricky part is i want to
 do this using a single query. ANY HELP ??**

Answer (score 0):

Use [NOT IN](http://www.w3resource.com/mysql/comparision-functions-and-operators/not-in.php):

```
SELECT `name`, `profile_pic` 
FROM `use_table` 
WHERE `username` = 'something' 
AND NOT IN (
    SELECT * FROM `use_table`
    WHERE `username` = 'something' AND `password` = 'something'
)
```

Comment: `You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'IN ( SELECT * FROM `

Answer (score 0):

quit easy, you just use the second query, but with password return like this:

```
SELCT `name`, `profile_pic`,`password` FROM `use_table` WHERE `username` = 'something'
```

### Then you do a compare with user input password and password that retured

if they matches, then login ok, else login failed!
but you also get the user's information!

Comment: i thought about it .. and its a good idea  but still i want to know if it is possible using a single query